# Div to sit onto of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

How can I get div `.mapoverlay` to sit onto of `#mapcanvas`. I'm guessing this can be achieved by altering the positioning with CSS but have tried and tried and cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map-canvas">
</div>
<div class="map-overlay">
    <div class="map-headline">
        <h3 class="blogheadline">Want to get in touch, we'd love to hear from you.   </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="map-address">
        <div class="map-address-icon"></div>
        <div class="map-address-name">Dan Morris</div>
        <div class="map-address-line-one">Gloucester Road, Horfield</div>
        <div class="map-address-line-two">Bristol, BS7 8PD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-contact-details">
        <div class="contact-icon-phone"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-contact-details"><div class="contact-icon-mail"></div>
    dan@danmorris.co.uk</div>
    <div class="directions-button">
        <a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"  id="map-direction">GET DIRECTIONS</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contact-map">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.contact-map {
    height: 560px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.map-overlay {
    height: 375px;
    width: 550px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

html, body, #map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Screenshot with coding above. Can see div is sitting behind map.

Comment: What do you mean by map overlay sit onto I think u mean inside of?

Comment: the two divs i have one has the class map overlay. need that one to sit onto of the div with id map-canvas

Comment: The map on this website is a good example of what i am trying to achieve. http://www.cacpro.com @zargold

Answer (score 1):

Try using `z-index: 10;` where `.map-overlay` has a higher number than `#map-canvas` this makes sure that `.map-overlay` is always on top of `#map-canvas`.
While positioning the `.map-overlay` element over the `#map-canvas`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to add next style and it worked

```
.map-overlay {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Can you give more information regarding positioning - how it should look like

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you mean that you would like the map overlay to be on top of the map-canvas.

So perhaps the best thing to do is:

```css
.contact-map {
height: 560px;
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin-top: 40px;

}

.map-overlay {
height: 375px;
width: 550px;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 100px;
background-color: #FFF;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
z-index:9999;

}

 html, body, #map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height:500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas">
  <div class="map-overlay">
  <div class="map-headline">
    <h3 class="blogheadline">Want to get in touch, we'd love to hear from you.   </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="map-address">
    <div class="map-address-icon"></div>
    <div class="map-address-name">Dan Morris</div>
    <div class="map-address-line-one">Gloucester Road, Horfield</div>
    <div class="map-address-line-two">Bristol, BS7 8PD</div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="map-contact-details">
     <div class="contact-icon-phone"></div>
    </div>
   <div class="map-contact-details"><div class="contact-icon-mail"></div>
    dan@danmorris.co.uk</div>
<div class="directions-button"><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll"  id="map-direction">GET DIRECTIONS</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="contact-map">
</div>
```

Notice how my blue map-canvas contains and has other stuff on top of it like the overlay that way the user can see the map you are showing and on top of it your contact info...

Comment: would it make a difference if there was something held inside div class contact map? I.e a google map?

Comment: Hi I think it works fine with google maps... I had a lot of trouble at first with my google map... you have to do `#map-canvas{
position:fixed;}` to make sure it has a normal size

Comment: i can get the map overlay div to sit ontop of the map canvas div but it pushes the map out?

Comment: want to provide a screenshot of how it looks like now?

Comment: have added a screen shot - with original coding as above you can see that the div is behind the map?

Comment: The map on this website is a good example of what i am trying to achieve. http://www.cacpro.com

Comment: try a z-index: 9999; on the div.